# Why doesn't a boolean get assigned to dropdown list via jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, dropdownlistfor

I have a dropdownlistfor having two fields IsOwner and Title.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(Model => Model.IsOwner, new SelectList(ZahidCarWash.ViewModels.AddServicesViewModel.FillDropDownIsOwnerOptions(), "IsOwner", "Title"), new { 
  @class = "form-control" 
})

// function:
public static List<ZahidCarWash.Models.IsOwnerSelection> FillDropDownIsOwnerOptions() 
{
  List<ZahidCarWash.Models.IsOwnerSelection> ListOwnerOptions = new List<ZahidCarWash.Models.IsOwnerSelection>();
  ListOwnerOptions.Add(new ZahidCarWash.Models.IsOwnerSelection() 
  { 
    IsOwner = true, 
    Title = "Yes" 
  });
  ListOwnerOptions.Add(new ZahidCarWash.Models.IsOwnerSelection() { 
    IsOwner = false, 
    Title = "No" 
  });

  return ListOwnerOptions;
}

// class
public class IsOwnerSelection
{
  public bool IsOwner { get; set; }
  public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to assign it a boolean value 'true' via jQuery but it doesn't. Why?

```
$("#IsOwner option:selected").val(false);
```

Comment: `$("#IsOwner').val('true');`

Comment: @StephenMuecke: not working, same issue

Comment: What is not working? What errors are you getting in the browser console?

Comment: none, that's the frustrating point

Comment: $('#IsOwner').val('True'); worked

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you need to set `val()` on the `select` element, not the `option`.

Secondly, when you call `ToString()` on a boolean value (as will be the case given the class you provide to `DropDownListFor()`) the first character is converted to uppercase, eg. `True` or `False`. Therefore you need to match this case when setting the value in jQuery. Try this:

```
$('#IsOwner').val('False');
```

Answer (score 0):

The dropdownlist items are capitalized so

```
 $('#IsOwner').val('true'); //Will not work

 $('#IsOwner').val('True'); //Works
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#IsOwner').val('true');
```

and

```
$('#IsOwner').val('false');
```

it will work here

Answer (score -1):

I think value of option is string. so you should try to assign as a string.

Comment: Have you tried to use $("#IsOwner").val('') to clear selected and to select $("#IsOwner").val('valueofanoption')?